# CCS Error[128] A #DEVICE required before this line

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded

I am getting

```
Error[128]   C:\Program Files\PICC\drivers\string.h 34 : A #DEVICE required before this line
```

when compiling simple helloWorld.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
printf("Hi");

}
```

i am compiling it by command `"ccsc +FM C:\vamshi\test\cFiles\Sample.c"`

am using **CCS, Inc. PCWHD Version 4**

Comment: And what exactly is at line 34 (and thereabouts) in `C:\Program Files\PICC\drivers\string.h` ?

Comment: @PaulR at line 34 there is first function definition, ie., till 33 we just have preprocessors and comments.................... char *memmove(void *s1,char *s2,size_t n)

Comment: @krishna:  In response to Paul's comment you should modify your question to include the necessary information rather than responing with a further comment.

Comment: It complains on that line because it does not know your device architecture and so cannot determine how to generate code for pointers. (I believe; I'm just reading the manual here ;-) - I've never used this compiler, and strive to avoid having to use a PIC of any flavour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [user manual](http://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf); the #DEVICE directive defines the behaviour of the compiler to accommodate the various PIC architectures and instruction set variations.  However, you would not normally place this directive directly in your code but rather `#include` the appropriate device header for your part. You have not been specific about what part you are using, but for example:

```
#include <pic16c63a.h>
```